# Android shared element transition between different scaleType

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I followed this [article of android develop blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html), and here is his [source code](https://github.com/android/animation-samples/tree/master/GridToPager).

The demo works well, however generally we prefer using `centerCrop` scale type in image list, and using `fitCenter` in detail mode. When I modify the code to achieve this, transition can't deal with the change of scale type. When back from detail fragemnt, the animation starts with wrong scale type.

[image]

I found the [`ChangeImageTransform`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/ChangeImageTransform) transition. The document says:

> This Transition captures an ImageView's matrix before and after the scene change and animates it during the transition.
>
> In combination with ChangeBounds, ChangeImageTransform allows ImageViews that change size, shape, or **ImageView.ScaleType** to animate contents smoothly.

So I changed the transition set:

```xml
<transitionSet
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="375"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:transitionOrdering="together">
  <changeBounds/>
  <changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

But the animation is getting much more ugly:

[image]

**How to transform between different scale type smoothly?**

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same project [GridToPager](https://github.com/android/animation-samples/tree/master/GridToPager) and faced the exact issue. Here are two changes that did the trick.

image_shared_element_transition.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="375"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:transitionOrdering="together">
  <changeClipBounds/>
  <changeTransform/>
  <changeBounds/>
  <changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

and

Remove `android:clipChildren="false"` attribute from CardView in image_card.xml

Answer (score 0):

When you use ChangeBounds, you need to transition the *child and parent* elements for the transition to work appropriately. Whenever the element enters from the top left corner like in your second video, you can assume that the parent view is not also being transitioned.
[image]
I would make sure the CardView is also treated as a shared element, which means you would need to update your second fragment layout so that the ImageView is inside a CardView.

Also note that every shared element needs a unique transitionName...this has caused issues for me in the past.

Comment: I try to remove the CardView wrapper instead, unfortunately  the issue is still there. BTW, the demo also use ChangeBounds without any problem. I am sure that transition name is unique, the blog highlights this.